# Node JS and AngularJS - script and links not found - 404

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, openshift

I am trying to build a Node.js/AngularJS app with Openshift 2. The server is being run successfully and if I go to local adress I get index.html(but blank as it does not load the css), I cant get scripts and links on index.html, I get an error 404 but I dont know why.

**Folder structure:**

```
sw [sw master]
    pages
         index.html
         inicio.html
    css
         inicio.css
    js
         angular.js 
         aplicacion.js                                      
    app.js
    start.js
```

**app.js**

```
const http         = require('http'),
      fs           = require('fs'),
      path         = require('path'),
      contentTypes = require('./utils/content-types'),
      sysInfo      = require('./utils/sys-info'),
      env          = process.env;

let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  let url = req.url;
  if (url == '/') {
    url += '/index.html';
  }

  // IMPORTANT: Your application HAS to respond to GET /health with status 200
  //            for OpenShift health monitoring

  if (url == '/health') {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
  } else if (url == '/info/gen' || url == '/info/poll') {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(sysInfo[url.slice(6)]()));
  } else {
    fs.readFile('./pages' + url, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end('Not found');
      } else {
        let ext = path.extname(url).slice(1);
        if (contentTypes[ext]) {
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentTypes[ext]);
        }
        if (ext === 'html') {
          res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store');
        }
        res.end(data);
      }
    });
  }
});

server.listen(env.NODE_PORT || 3000, env.NODE_IP || 'localhost', function () {
  console.log(`Application worker ${process.pid} started...`);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" data-ng-app="TFG">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Página principal</title>

        <script src="../js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/app.js"></script>    
        <link href="../css/inicio.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>

    <body>  

        <!--CUERPO-->
        <div data-ng-view></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you run your server on localhost? And which local address you have mentioned?

Comment: I run the app like node.js aplication on 127.0.0.1:3000

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js script running the server will render html from page folder. This index.html has the css and js linked by relative path from the folder structure but you need to expose that publicly too to get reached by the browser when it tries to get the resources. You will need some code to serve that static content.

In fact, is your own code returning that 404 as the URL that the browser is trying to get the resources (css and js) from your pages folder and they are not found.

```
 fs.readFile('./pages' + url, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end('Not found');
      }
```

You should include some code that return the css and js files.

Answer (score 0):

your index file should be at root level as you are providing path in your nodejs file.
Right now your index.html is under "pages" folder.
pages
         index.html
         inicio.html

I think this will be your tree

sw [sw master]
    pages
         inicio.html
    css
         inicio.css
    js
         angular.js 
         aplicacion.js 
    *emphasized text*index.html
    app.js
    start.js

Comment: I thought that, but this is what Openshift gave me when I created the application: https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs/tree/master/usr/template

Comment: Must follow those github link in which they also provide description.

Comment: Otherwise you have to sent path for css, js from server.